# Flutter debugger not showing error where it occurred in my Flutter app files

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

Flutter debugger is not showing the error where it occurred in my Flutter app files, instead, it shows the specific flutter file in which the error occurred this has made me unable to track where the error came from in my file. I get this when using flutter in vscode. The error is that I used a null check on a null value.

Comment: if it is referring to the source code, maybe you are using wrong widget/pattern

Comment: Please could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Answer (score 1):

Flutter does this with a few errors, had the same issue with a declaration error where data from a JSON was int and I declared it as a list. I found that running it and inspecting the console on the HTML page sometimes helps and shows more info. If you could post the specific error it would be easier to help you find a solution.

Comment: I have added a gif which shows how this happens also I have found the solution to the problem I just want to make sure that next time it shows where the error is coming from, so debugging can be more efficient.